# In hadoop what is meant by ability to preserve state across mapper reducer multiple inputs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The heading of the question explains everything what my question is. 
I have been reading through multiple texts, answers where I came across this line

> Through use of the combiner and by taking advantage of the ability to
>   preserve state across multiple inputs, it is often possible to
>   substantially reduce both the number and size of key-value pairs that
>   need to be shuffled from the mappers to the reducers.

I am not able to understand this concept. An elaborate answer and explanation with an example would be really helpful. How to develop an intuition to understand such concepts?

Answer (score 0):

If you already feel comfortable with the "reducer" concept, a combiner concept will be easy. A combiner can be seen as a mini-reducer on the map phase. What i mean by that?  Lets see an example: suppose that you are doing the classic wordcount problem, you know that for every word  a key-value pair is emited by the mapper. Then the reducer will take as input this key-value pairs and summaryze them. 
Supose that a mapper collects some key-value pairs like:

```
<key1,1>,
<key2,1>,
<key1,1>,
<key3,1>,
<key1,1>
```

If you are not using a combiner, this 4 key-value pairs will be sent to the reducer. but using a combiner we could perform a pre-reduce in the mapper, so the output of the mapper will be:

```
<key1,3>,
<key2,1>,
<key3,1>
```

In this simple example by using a combiner, you reduced the total number of key-value pairs from 5 to 3, which will give you less network traffic and better performance in the shuffle phase.

Comment: Yes. I completely understand what you are saying, but my question is regarding the state....I don't understand the statement : ability to preserve state across multiple inputs.....? what is that? where have we maintained state here?

Comment: Or do you mean to say that the aggregation which we performed maintained the state?

Comment: Well, this is a bit related to how the map-reduce framework operates internally. The framework instantiates a Mapper object, this has the map method that you defined, but since the same Mapper object applies the map method to multiple key-value pairs in the input split , it is capable of preserving the state across multiple key-value pairs inputs,a simple example of this state could be  a counter for every key it encounters. It could even load "state" data at "setup" time and preserve it(or update it) across multiple inputs.

Comment: Can you elaborate this more with a simple explanation?